# Program causing errors after MSI installation

Tags: c#, excel, csv, windows-installer, converters

I created an msi installer of my C# VS2008 program. The program reads in data from an xml file located in the installation folder, and copies an excel file that can be found in the same folder.

When I run this in either Debug mode, or Release mode, it works fine. However, after using the MSI installer, and I use the real executable, I get the following errors:

> Error: Access to path C:\ is denied. (This has now been resolved)
>
> Error: No matching profile found. Contact your service provider. (This has now been resolved.)
>
> Error: The given key was not present in the dictionary. (This happened
>   on another machine, a laptop, when trying to convert from csv to
>   excel.)

Any ideas on what could be causing this after the MSI install?

Edit: The first two errors have been resolved, however, the third error still persists.

Comment: Your code is using a dictionary class, probably related to the xml file, and after you read it in you are referencing a key that does not exist. I'm guessing because you haven't said anything about what your program actually does with the xml file. This should be easy to debug by making your code a little smarter and testing that the key exists before using it. You might have loaded the wrong Xml file. You're asking us to figure out why your code doesn't work with an Xml file without showing the code or the Xml from the actual install folder!

Comment: Yeah, I've managed to find it. For some reason, on one computer, it accepted Workbooks.Worksheets[1] as a selection for the Excel worksheet I was transferring information to, but on another computer, it thought it was out of bounds. I fixed it by entering in the name of the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity: which .NET framework are you using on your build machine and which .NET framework is installed on the laptop? You also need Windows Installer installed. Versions matter, so check if you have the same Windows Installer versions installed on you build machine and on the laptop.

Comment: On my machine, I am coding in VS2008 .Net 3.5, and the laptop has at least 4.5 for .Net.

Comment: what about windows installer? are the both 32bit of x64?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I need to figure out how to check that.

Comment: you can go to addremove programs or add remove windows features and just look up the version. Other option is to go to program files folder and see there.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is working fine on the developer machine, it is likely to be a missing component that is required by the program. It might be that the component (DLL, etc.) may not be registered on the target computer. Make sure the the installer installs and registers all the components required by the program.

***/Updated after the first comment/***

Furthermore, you can find what are the references being used on the solution properties. See the below image,

[image]

This will tell what are references being used. Moreover, anything that says **True** in the *Copy Local* column needs to be in the same folder as the program on the target computer and must be registered. **False** means these are in the .NET framework it-self and no need to be copied to the target computer since it will be in the .NET framework it-self.

In addition, you can use the following command to register the components,

On 32bit computer:

> "regsvr32.exe" "component file path and name"

On 64bit computer:

> "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\regsvr32.exe" "component file path and name"

You can run this via a VBScript (*.vbs) file.

Comment: How do I go about knowing what things are required? I've included the DLL and all necessary files. I guess it's the Register part of this that I might be missing.